# Web API method will work for string but not integers

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I have written a method in web api to partial update/patch a user. The code goes like this :

```
  // PATCH API USER
    [AcceptVerbs("PATCH")]
    public HttpResponseMessage PatchDoc(int id, Delta<user> user)
    {
            user changeduser = db.users.SingleOrDefault(p => p.iduser == id);
            if (changeduser == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            user.Patch(changeduser);
            db.SaveChanges();
       return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

Its working fine if i am using updating/patching a string property like :

```
{location: "London,Uk"}
```

It works fine. But if i update/patch an integer property it doesnt makes changes, the field remains the same.

```
{profileviews: 43}
```

I even tried using json like

```
{profileviews: "43"}
```

But still no change. So what am i missing? Thanks.

Comment: What does your `user.Patch(User)` method do?

Comment: I see that the intention is to patch the user based on the method name but the method looks like the most obvious candidate to where your problem is. Can you post the implementation?

Comment: This is the method : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj890126(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: public void Patch(TEntityType original);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Overwrites the original entity with the values stored in this Delta.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   original:
        //     The entity to be updated.